# How to specify a url for Iphone web clip?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-touch-icon, web-clips

I can specify an icon for web clip.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

It's Ok. So, I would like to specify my homepage url for the web clip when the visitors even add it to their home screen via sub pages. Currently, when I click the icon it opens the sub page that I don't want.

Is that possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike [Android Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen) and its `start_url` manifest attribute, the [Apple Touch icon](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) has no such feature.

Sure it's hard to prove that something doesn't exist, but I never encountered anything like this in the iOS sphere.